# Replace Words with a linebreak

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

This is my Textfile (temp.txt):

> (test1 AND id=42343) AND NOT (test2 AND id=12234) AND NOT (test3 AND id=12342) AND NOT (test4 AND id=13342)

I have to replace all  ")AND NOT(" so that the file after formatation look like this:

> test1 AND id=42343 
> test2 AND id=12234
> test3 AND id=12342
> test4 AND id=13342

I tried this Script/Command:

```
(Get-Content C:\temp.txt) |ForEach-Object{$_ -replace "[) AND NOT (]","`n`r"}|Set-Content C:\temp.txt
```

But now the textfile looks terrible:

> es
>   1
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   i
>   =42343
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   es
>   2
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   i
>   =12234
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   es
>   3
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   i
>   =12342
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   es
>   4
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   i
>   =13342

So what is wrong with my Command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$a = "(test1 AND id=42343) AND NOT (test2 AND id=12234) AND NOT (test3 AND id=12342) AND NOT (test4 AND id=13342)"
$a.Replace(") AND NOT (", "`r`n").TrimStart("(").TrimEnd(")") | Out-File E:\2.txt
```

You don't really need regex here, or even a loop

Comment: The Linebreaks wont displayed in the original text file. But when I copy the content in another textfile the linebreaks are displayed. And is there a way to remove the first and the last superfluous parentheses?

Comment: See update, I don;t understand what you mean with line breaks

Comment: thx removing works fine! So I do an `Out-File C:\temp2.txt` and when I open this file I see the text correctly formatted but there are no Line Breaks (<br>)displayed. But when I copy the text and paste it in another text file it works and I can see the Linebreaks. But I need it correct in the first file.

Comment: You should do `"`r`n"` not other way around, see update