# Replace Linebreak with Characters

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I want to replace my linebreaks with a character.

Before:

> Test1
> Test2
> Test3
> Test4

After:

> Test1|Test2|Test3|Test4

For this I tried following Script:

```
$a=Get-Content "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test2.txt"   
$a=$a.Replace("`r`n","|")
```

But this gives me the following:

> Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4

What did I wrong?
I ask a similar question couple of hours ago: [Replace Word with a Linebreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36763013/replace-words-with-a-linebreak/36763250?noredirect=1#comment61107136_36763250)

But it dont help me at my current Problem.

Comment: Works :) But why the "|" "knows" where they have to go?

Comment: `|` just join elements of your array. So, it just go between elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$a=Get-Content "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test2.txt" -raw  
$a=$a -Replace '\n', '|'
```

the -raw parameter will make the content to be threated as a single string

Comment: Works also fine! Thanks a lot

Comment: I think `-Raw` is not available in PS3 or higher

Comment: Weird : only documented in v5 on MSDN : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849787(v=wps.640).aspx

Comment: @sodawillow It documented for v3. See [end of the page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847764%28v=wps.620%29.aspx).